# What is internal space translation?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, time-crystals

While I was reading the paper named "Classical time crystals," by A. Shapere and F. Wilczek, I found the following transformation.

$$f(x) \to f(x+e) - \frac{df}{dx}*e$$

It says the transformation is combined internal space-real space translation.

What is internal space translation (I guess it is $f(x) \to f(x+e) - \frac{df}{dx}*e$?) in both mathematical and physical sense?

The paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2537). The aforementioned formula is at the first paragragh of second column.

Comment: Not sure physically.. but mathematically isn't it just the first two teams of a taylor expansion of a translation $e$ in $x$?

Comment: Should "$e$" be "$\epsilon$", i.e., a differentially small displacement?

Comment: Pretty cool paper!

Comment: Thank everyone for editting. This was my first question so I was not familiar with all this.     Yes, e should be epsilon.

Comment: What is the $*$ operation?

Answer (score 0):

The paper refers to a combined internal space-real space transformation.The first part, $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(x+\epsilon)$, is a **real space traslation**, as it shifts the position coordinate by $\epsilon$ as $x \rightarrow x+\epsilon$.

The second part, $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(x) -\epsilon\frac{d\phi}{dx}$, is the **internal transformation**. This naming comes from the fact that this transformation is acting on the angular variable itself ( or the field in the context of QFT or electromagnetism) and not on the spacetime as the traslation $x\rightarrow x+\epsilon$.

This is a kind of [gauge transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory). The easiest to visualize is perhaps the [electromagnetic gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Gauge_freedom) $^1$ where you write the vector potential $\textbf{A}$ as $\textbf{A} + \nabla f$ and the electric potential as $V \rightarrow V - \frac{df}{dt}$ which affect neither any of the "real" degrees of freedom of the system nor the fields ($\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{E}$) themselves.

1. Classical Electrodynamics (1962). JD Jackson. Section 6.4 .